# Scala: how to get max partition from hdfs dir

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am using scala.

I want to filter latest folder and read only latest and also all files in it from hdfs dir.

Now it looks like

```scala
val read_csv = 
  spark
    .read
    .format("csv")
    .load( "hdfs://device/signs/load=16»)
```

in the folder **signs** there are few folders with load (load=10, load=13, load=14, load=16) and I want to get only max value.

Comment: I expect that you can just load the entire folder, then filter `df.where(col("load)===16)`, partition pruning should do the rest. You should check the query-plan

Otherwise use Hadoop File System API to list your folders and find the latest one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this methos:

```
  private def getMaxPartitionValue(path: String, partitionName: String, sparkSession: SparkSession): String = {
    // This will create a Path object using the hadoop configuration used in the spark session        
    val hdfs = new Path(path).getFileSystem(sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    // This will filter all folders that starts with the partition name, in your case load=
    val partitionNames = hdfs.listStatus(new Path(path)).toList.filter(_.getPath.getName.startsWith(partitionName + "="))
    // if no partition starts with load= the we return an empty string
    if (partitionNames.isEmpty) return ""
    // this is to only get the partition value ( everything after load=) and then get the max value of all these partitions
    partitionNames.map(_.getPath.getName).sorted.reverse.head
  }
```

Call it like this:

```
val maxPartitionPath = path + File.separator + getMaxPartitionValue(path, "load", sparkSession)
```

Comment: it is work! Thank you so much. But it is  too sad I don't understand how it works. thanks again ;)

Comment: @Pluto I added some comments, let me know if something is not clear

Comment: more than enough, you are very very welcome. 
Of course there are some questions, but that's another story))@Abdennacer Lachiheb

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using hive metastore in your stack, you can find out latest partition with Hadoop FS API. You can get access to files metadata and handle it in the way you need:

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val fs = FileSystem.get(sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
      
val ls = fs.listStatus(new Path("/"))
```

If you have metastore on your cluster, you can get access to partitions with sql

```scala
sparkSession.sql("SHOW PARTITIONS tablename")
```

Comment: thanks to your answer, it turned out to display a list of folders: hdfs://device/signs/load=10, hdfs://device/signs/load=13, hdfs://device/signs/load=14, hdfs://device/signs/load=16, but I still have a question, how to leave only maximum value (load=16)